# Fire an event on scrollend of the screen

Tags: react-native, native-base

I want to fire an event at the scroll end of the app screen. I am using the native base card and list view. I tried within onscrollend event. But nothing seems to work. Is there any better way to detect the scroll end of the screen?

Comment: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2044

Answer (score 3):

Use **onEndReached** function in **ListView** Component, it Called when all rows have been rendered and the list has been scrolled to within **onEndReachedThreshold** of the bottom. The native scroll event is provided.

**onEndReachedThreshold** Threshold in pixels (virtual, not physical) for calling onEndReached.

So as I see it: if you do **onEndReachedThreshold ={100}** it calls onEndReached if you scrolled to 100 pixels from the bottom

**Example:**

```
          <ListView
            {..........} 
            onEndReachedThreshold={100}
            onEndReached={() => {
                            console.log("fired"); // keeps firing
                          }}

           />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onEndReached and onEndReachedTreshold props of  component. 
Flatlist is better choice to do infinite scrolling than ListView.